# threejs disable orbit camera while using transform control

Tags: javascript, three.js, transformation, raycasting

I have a scene with multiple meshes, each one of them associated to a different transformControl; in order to select different objects, I'm using raycasting techniques. I'm also using an orbit camera in order to navigate the scene.

Whenever I modify the position/rotation/scale of the selected object using transform control, I want to disable orbit camera, because sometimes while I'm clicking on a picker, I'm also picking on the background of the scene, so the orbit camera moves.

I'd like to stop this behavior and I've already tried to handle it with raycasting techniques, but it doesn't work.

Comment: controls.enable = false; to disable OrbitControls. You disable it for example if your raycaster does not return any objects and enable it on mouseUp again?

Comment: That's right. I've already tried doing what you suggest, but I doesn't work. It seems that the raycaster doesn't work while the mouse is over the transform control pickers, even if i can use those picker. I really don't understand..

Comment: maybe check the threejs Editor code, because well, it is implemented there. ^^

Comment: controls.enabled = false

Comment: should be `controls.enableRotate  = false;`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Stumbled over this and thought it would be helpful to see the answer (credits to BuildingJarl):

```
// if youre definition is like
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

// you can easily disable it by using
controls.enabled = false;
```

In my case I was using a UI overlay and I got issues with getting the focus to it. Disabling the controls solved my problems.

Greetings Mat

Comment: this answer is in the comments of the question.

Comment: as I already said: credits to BuildingJarl... but this way you can see the answer directly. Just found it helpful. greetings

Comment: To add some information beside, if you need to disable the cursor keys as well, use `controls.noPan = false;`. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Answer (score 5):

Taken from three.js editor's example code, you can just disable orbitControls when transformControls are used:

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { TransformControls } from 'three/addons/controls/TransformControls.js';

let orbitControls= new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
orbitControls.addEventListener('change', render);

let transformControls = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
transformControls.addEventListener('change', render);
transformControls.attach(targetObject);
transformControls.addEventListener('dragging-changed', function (event) {
    orbitControls.enabled = !event.value;
});
```

On every dragging of the controls, the orbitControls will be set `orbitControls.enabled = false`.

Note that if you have `targetObject.matrixAutoUpdate = false` then you need to call `targetObject.updateMatrix()` before `render` in the `change` event handler.